# JavaFX 2.x : Chart set X and Y axis css font color

Tags: css, fonts

How to set Font color for X and Y axis?

In [css reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont) for fonts I have found only

```
font-size, font-style and font-weight
```

but nothing about font color. I have tried

```
-fx-font-color
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help

**Edit:**

This is my situation:

```
Set<Node> axisNode = lineChart.lookupAll(".axis");
        for(final Node axis : axisNode){

            axis.setStyle("-fx-minor-tick-visible:false;");
            axis.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 8;")
            axis.setStyle("-fx-font-color: red;");
        }
```

I can't figure out how to use only

```
 color:#008800;
```

Comment: Found the right solution: "-fx-tick-label-fill: red;"

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is that you want to chnage the chart axis font color, for that you can must add this code in your css file :

```
.axis-label { -fx-text-fill: #008800; }
```